Subtle difference between for loop and for_each
I've been coding in Rust for some time but I am often caught off-guard by these nuances.
For example, this works:
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
fn main() {
    let all_threads: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    
    for t in all_threads {
         t.join().unwrap();
    }
}

This doesn't (error: cannot move out of *t which is behind a shared reference)
fn main() {
    let all_threads: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    
    all_threads.iter_mut().for_each(move |t| t.join().unwrap());
}

I was under the impression that the snippet above was syntactic sugar for the one below, but clearly I am missing something. Can someone help me how does the for loop move instances out?

for loops use into_iter, not iter_mut. https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops

Also as can be seen from the reference drewtato linked, and the source of for_each neither for_each nor for is syntax sugar for each other, apart from similar semantics, they are completely different things.

for loops in Rust are actually a syntactic sugar for using the IntoIterator trait, not IterMut, as used in your example. You can see the exact details on how the desugaring is done exactly in the Rust docs.
Knowing that, we can change the example from your question so that it compiles now:
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

fn main() {
    let all_threads: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];

    all_threads.into_iter().for_each(move |t| t.join().unwrap());
}

The reason your original code doesn't work is the subtle difference in borrowing semantics. IterMut::Iterator implementation yields &mut T (mutable references to T), while IntoIterator::IntoIter yields T objects (owned objects). Since JoinHandle::join() requires self (i.e. it consumes the object), it won't work with a mutable reference returned by IterMut.
